# 2 inner joins between same 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select columns from 2 tables,

The `INNER JOIN` conditions are `$table1.idaction_url=$table2.idaction` AND `$table1.idaction_name=$table2.idaction`.

However, From the query below, there is no output. It seems like the INNER JOIN can only take 1 condition. If I put `AND` to include both conditions as shown in the query below, there wont be any output. Please look at the picture below. Please advice.

[image]

```
 $mysql=("SELECT conv(hex($table1.idvisitor), 16, 10) as visitorId,
 $table1.server_time, $table1.idaction_url, 
$table1.time_spent_ref_action,$table2.name,
 $table2.type, $table1.idaction_name, $table2.idaction
FROM $table1 
INNER JOIN $table2 
   ON $table1.idaction_url=$table2.idaction 
   AND $table1.idaction_name=$table2.idaction
WHERE conv(hex(idvisitor), 16, 10)='".$id."'  
ORDER BY server_time DESC");
```

Comment: You have to use aliasses for the table

Comment: An inner join can most definitely have such a condition. Could you supply some sample data? It would help us help you.

Comment: @Mureinik I added a picture to see the sample data. If you think this would in $table1 column idaction_url and idaction_name both point to column name in table 2. The desired output, idaction_url contains the url and the idaction_name display the title of the url page. The desired output is on the left figure in the picture. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You need to use two separate inner joins, not only a single join.

E.g.

```
SELECT `actionurls`.`name` AS `actionUrl`, `actionnames`.`name` AS `actionName` 
FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN  `table2` AS `actionurls` ON `table1`.`idaction_url` = `actionurls`.`idaction`
INNER JOIN  `table2` AS `actionnames` ON `table1`.`idaction_name` = `actionurls`.`idaction`
```

(Modify this query with any additional fields you want to select).

**In depth**: `INNER JOIN`, when done on a value unique to the second table (the table joined to the first in this operation) will only ever fetch one row. What you want to do is fetch data from the other table twice, into the same row, reading the select part of the statement.

`INNER JOIN table2 ON [comparison]` will, for each row selected from `table1`, grab any rows from `table2` for which `[comparison]` is `TRUE`, then copy the row from `table1` **N** times, where **N** is the amount of rows found in `table2`. If **N = 0**, then the row is skipped. In our case **N=1** so `INNER JOIN` of `idaction_name` in `table1` to `idaction` in `table2` for example will allow you to select all the action names.

In order to get the action urls as well we have to `INNER JOIN` a second time. Now you can't join the same table twice normally, as SQL won't know which of the two joined tables is meant when you type `table2.name` in the first part of your query. This would be ambiguous if both had the same name. There's a solution for this, [table aliases](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/).

The output (of my answer above) is going to be something like:

```
+-----+------------------------+-------------------------+
| Row |       actionUrl        |       actionName        |
+-----+------------------------+-------------------------+
|   1 | unx.co.jp/             | UNIX | Kumamoto Home    |
|   2 | unx.co.jp/profile.html | UNIX | Kumamoto Profile |
| ... | ...                    | ...                     |
+-----+------------------------+-------------------------+
```

While if you used only a single join, you would get this kind of output (using `OR`):

```
+-----+-------------------------+
| Row |       actionUrl         |
+-----+-------------------------+
|   1 | unx.co.jp/              |
|   2 | UNIX | Kumamoto Home    |
|   3 | unx.co.jp/profile.html  |
|   4 | UNIX | Kumamoto Profile |
| ... | ...                     |
+-----+-------------------------+
```

Using `AND` and a single join, you only get output if `idaction_name == idaction_url` is `TRUE`. This is not the case, so there's no output.

If you want to know more about how to use JOINS, consult the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) about them.

**Sidenote**

Also, I can't help but notice you're using variables (e.g. `$table1`) that store the names of the tables. Do you make sure that those values do not contain user input? And, if they do, do you at least whitelist a list of tables that users can access? You may have some security issues with this.

Comment: since the table names are long, I use `$table1="long_table_names";` but this gives me error, unknown tables.column . . .

Comment: Are there spaces in the real table name? E.g. a table named "unx profiles" has to be escaped in your query. Try using `\`unx profiles\`` instead of `unx profiles`.
My examples use `table1` and `table2` as the table names. Replace these with the real names and they should work.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have added `OR` to the `ON` clause to make it `INNER JOIN $table2 ON $table1.idaction_url=$table2.idaction OR $table1.idaction_name=$table2.idaction` however, when I call the variables, `$url = $row['name']; This is to call  only the first condition of the No clause. I can not think of another way to call the second condition in order to make it look like your second table. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` does not put any restriction on number of conditions it can have.

The zero resultant rows means, there is no rows satisfying the two conditions simultaneously.

Make sure you are joining using correct columns. Try going step by step to identify from where the data is lost

Comment: thanks for the answer. I believe the query do not pick up the second join condition, and Im wondering why?